# Not able to add the list into new row of CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, row, export-to-csv, read.csv

```
List = ['Mean', mean]
List2 = ["Variance", variance]
List3 = ["SD", std]

rows = zip(List, List2, List3)

from csv import writer
with open(r'E:\chrome dlds\null - Sheet1.csv', "a", newline = '') as f:
    writer = writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)


with open(r'E:\chrome dlds\null - Sheet1.csv', mode ='r') as file:
    csvFile = csv.reader(file)
    for lines in csvFile:
            print(lines)
```

[image: code snippet]

I tried to add lists (List,List1,List2) into CSV file as a new row and expected output to read the lists as new rows.

I am new to CSV module so When using writer function, The output is adding List into last column of the CSV file. I want the list to append as a new row into csv file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your original file doesn't end with a newline. So the first row of `rows` is being appended to the end of the last line of the file, instead of as a new line.

Comment: The way to fix this is to read all the lines of the file first, and check whether the last one ends with `'\n'`. If it doesn't, write a newline before the loop that writes the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the original file ends with newline. If not, add it before writing new rows.

```
import os

with open(r'E:\chrome dlds\null - Sheet1.csv', "a+", newline = '') as f:
    f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    lastchar = f.read(1)
    # Add newline at the end if necessary
    if lastchar != '\n':
        f.write('\n')
    writer = writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```